# Looping through "find" result in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop through a bunch of files in a bash script, in particular all jar in my hive maven repo.

I wrote the following code :

```
for f in $(find /home/c4stor/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/  -iname '*.jar'); do
  echo "Jar found :":$f;
done
```

When I execute this in my terminal, I have the following result :

```
Jar found :/home/c4stor/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-serde/0.10.0-cdh4.2.1/hive-serde-0.10.0-cdh4.2.1.jar
Jar found :/home/c4stor/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-common/0.9.0/hive-common-0.9.0.jar
(etc....)
```

When I run my bash script with the exact same content, it goes like this :

```
Jar found :/home/c4stor/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-serde/0.10.0-cdh4.2.1/hive-serde-0.10.0-cdh4.2.1.jar /home/c4stor/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-common/0.9.0/hive-common-0.9.0.jar (etc....)
```

i.e the for is looping on a single element compound of all the filepath concatenated. Which is not what I would have desired.

Does anyone have a clue :
1. Why it is behaving this way ?
2. How to have the script behave like the terminal ?

Thanks :)
C4stor

Comment: It works for me.. How do you invoke your bash script (Do you have a "bang" comment on the first line, etc.)? What OS etc. are you on?

Comment: Does your bash script set `IFS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why it is behaving this way ?

`for` depends on `$IFS`. You've changed `$IFS` and hence how `for` works.

> How to have the script behave like the terminal ?

```
find ... -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f
do
   ...
done
```

[or...](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

```
while read -d $'\0' f
do
   ...
done < <(find ... -print0)
```